# Leaflet how to change marker interactivity

Tags: leaflet

I can change interactivity of a marker this way

```
const position = [x, y];
const map = L.map('map').setView(position, z);
L.tileLayer(url, options).addTo(map);
var marker = L.marker([x, y], { interactive: false }).addTo(map);

const button = document.getElementById("button");
let interactive = false;
button.onclick = () => {
    interactive = !interactive;
    marker.removeFrom(map);
    L.setOptions(marker, { interactive: interactive });
    marker.addTo(map);
};
```

Here I have to first remove marker from map, second change options and third add to map again.

Is there a way to change options of an existing marker already added to map without removing it and adding it again ?

Answer (score -1):

You can call direct the object.

```
let interactive = false;
button.onclick = () => {
    interactive = !interactive;
    marker.options.interactive = interactive;
};
```

or use `setStyle()`, then the marker will be rerenderd:

```
let interactive = false;
button.onclick = () => {
    interactive = !interactive;
    marker.setStyle({interactive: interactive});
};
```

But I would recommend not use a global flag. Because you will become a problem, if you want to use more then one marker.

I would use this:

```
button.onclick = () => {
    marker.options.interactive = !marker.options.interactive;
};
```

Comment: neither solution work, setting object directly has no effect and marker has no setStyle function